# Jenkins: Android Emulator Plugin - No Such File

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I am new to jenkins. i am trying to build a sample espresso test with jenkins emulator. Below is the error of my jenkins. Please help. Thanks!

Click Here for my picture of Android Emulator Configuration:
[image: image path]

Invoke Gradle Script:
[image: image path]

```
 [android] Starting Android emulator
 $ /home/jenkins-slave/tools/android-sdk/emulator/emulator -skin 480x800 -ports 5754,5755 -report-console tcp:5836,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-6_mySuffix
 /home/jenkins-slave/tools/android-sdk/emulator/emulator: error while 
 loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 [android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
 [android] Stopping Android emulator
 $ /home/jenkins-slave/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
 Finished: NOT_BUILT
```